# In the PRINCE2 process model, when is the project management team structure reviewed?

Tags: prince2

During the lifecycle of a project, the project management team might evolve or change. Where in the PRINCE2 process model is this project management team structure being reviewed, and updated if required?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "be reviewed"? By whom and reviewed under what criteria? How often is "often"?

Comment: Who else has authority to review the Project Management team in a prince2? I am guessing the board itself. Also , once a project team is created and the project is under going, should it be reviewed at all by the project board during the project term. Or is it a responsibility by the assurance people / project manager.

Comment: Asking more questions, as opposed to answering the ones I asked, has not clarified exactly what you are asking. Voting to close.

Comment: In the original format, this wasn't a good question. One tip is to avoid putting your personal bias in the question or providing your opinion in the question. Instead, keep it objective.  Since the editor fixed these issues and made the question more objective, it's now open for answers from the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PRINCE2, the project management team structure is set up during the *Starting up a Project* process:

> Individuals are appointed who will undertake the work required in project initiation and/or will take significant project management roles in the project
>
> *(source: "Managing Successful Projects with PRINCE2", a.k.a. the PRINCE2 manual; section 12.2)*

The activities where this happens are *Appoint the Executive and the Project Manager* and *Design and appoint the project management team* (see sections 12.4.1 & 12.4.3 in the PRINCE2 manual).

While we are executing the *Initiating a Project* process, we build a more detailed view of the project, and might alter or further develop the project management team. These are some examples:

- We did not have sufficient detail yet during Starting up to fill in all roles and we merely created a skeleton with the bare minimum.
- Or we now know who will be the team managers for the first delivery stage.
- Or a Project Board member decides to appoint Project Assurance to a dedicated person.

So during *Initiating a Project*, we can review, refine, update the project management team structure, if relevant. This is being considered during the activity *Set up the project controls*:

> ...this may include finalizing any roles not previously allocated, re-allocating roles previously filled and, if necessary, re-designing the project management team
>
> *(PRINCE2 manual, section 14.4.5)*

Finally, also during the *Managing a Stage Boundary* process, we (re)consider the compostion of te project management team:

> Review and, if necessary, update the Project Initiation Documentation (in particular the ... **project management team structure and role descriptions**)
>
> *(PRINCE2 manual, sections 17.2 & 17.4.2)*

To summarize:

- the project management team structure is set up during *Starting up a Project*
- and reviewed and updated, if required, during *Initiating a Project* and *Managing a Stage Boundary*